# Implementing Something like QDockWidget::togleViewAct for regular widgets

Tags: c++, qt

just trying to get this working, I don't understand why it doesn't work. compiled with Qt Creator on Windows 7 x64, but I don't think that should matter too much.

mainwindow.h:

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

class QAction;
class QMenu;
class QWidget;

class mywidget;

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow();

private:
    void createActions();
    void createMenus();

    mywidget *thewidget;

    QMenu *viewMenu;

    QAction *toggleViewAct;
};

#endif
```

mywidget.h:

```
#ifndef MYWIDGET_H
#define MYWIDGET_H

#include <QWidget>

class mywidget : public QWidget
{

public:
    mywidget(QWidget *parent){ m_parent = parent ; }

private slots:
    void toggleView(){ isHidden() ? setVisible(true) : setVisible(false) ; }

private:
    QWidget *m_parent;
};

#endif
```

mainwindow.cpp:

```
#include <QtWidgets>

#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "mywidget.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow()
{
    thewidget = new mywidget(new QWidget());

    thewidget->setWindowTitle("test");

    thewidget->setVisible(true);

    createActions();
    createMenus();
}

void MainWindow::createActions()
{
    toggleViewAct = new QAction(tr("Toggle other widget"), this);
    toggleViewAct->setStatusTip(tr("toggle tabbed widgets visibility"));
    connect(toggleViewAct, SIGNAL(triggered()), thewidget, SLOT(toggleView()));
}

void MainWindow::createMenus()
{
    viewMenu = menuBar()->addMenu(tr("&Menu"));
    viewMenu->addAction(toggleViewAct);
}
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <QApplication>

#include "mainwindow.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    app.setOrganizationName("QtProject");
    app.setApplicationName("Application Example");
    MainWindow mainWin;

    mainWin.show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: Add the `Q_OBJECT` macro for `mywidget` class and rebuild again.

Comment: Same as before. Pressing the menu button does nothing to the second window.

Comment: Check whether the `toggleView()` slot called at all.

Comment: I don't think it does. using the Creator to put a breakpoint on `toggleview()`'s line and the program doesn't pause.

Comment: App Output gives me `QObject::connect: No such slot QWidget::toggleView()`

Comment: Did you run qmake after adding Q_OBJECT macro to mywidget?